# chart.js django - options doesnt work for chart

Tags: python, django, charts, chart.js

I just made my first chart using chart.js in django. But I cant edit it with any options.

```
The code in template looks like: 
$.get('{% url "line_chart_json" %}', function(data) {    
    var options = {showTooltips: true, tooltipTemplate: "<%= value %>"};
    var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
    new Chart(ctx).Bar(data, options);
    });
```

For example when I change "new Chart(ctx).**Bar**(data, options);" to "new Chart(ctx).**Line**(data, options);" it works, but other options doesnt work.

Thanks for help!

Comment: What `other` options? What doesn't work? Be more descriptive.

Comment: For example this options works:
                scaleGridLineColor: 'grey',
                scaleLineColor : 'grey',
                animationEasing : 'easeOutBounce',

but every option connected with TOOLTIP doesnt work. I also find the bug in tooltipTemplate -> it cant be <%= value %> becouse my values comes from view class in views.py. Data works ok on chart but cant import it to tooltipTemplate :(